# Copy remote postgres database to second remote server

Tags: python, postgresql, azure-functions, pgadmin, pg-dump

I currently have a prod and test database that live on 2 servers azure postgres servers. I want to do a nightly backup of the prod database onto test, such that every morning the two are identical. My datatables have contraints and keys, so I can't just copy over the data itself but also the schemas, so a simple pandas df.to_sql won't cover it.

My current plan is to run a nightly Azure Functions python script that does the copying over. I tried sqlalchemy but had significant issues copying over metadata correctly.
Now I am trying to use postgres' pg_dump and pg_restore/psql commands via a subprocess with the following code:

```
def backup_database(location, database, password, username, backup_file):
    # Use pg_dump command to create a backup of the specified database
    cmd = [
        'pg_dump',
        '-Fc',
        '-f', backup_file,
        '-h', location,
        '-d', database,
        '-U', username,
        '-p', '5432',
        '-W',
    ]
    subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, input=password.encode())

def clear_database(engine, metadata):
    # Drop all tables in the database
    metadata.drop_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=False)

def restore_database(location, database, password, username, backup_file):
    # Use pg_restore command to restore the backup onto the database
    # cmd = ['pg_restore', '-Fc', '-d', engine.url.database, backup_file]
    cmd = [
        'pg_restore',
        '-Fc',
        '-C',
        '-f', backup_file,
        '-h', location,
        #'-d', database,
        '-U', username,
        '-p', '5432',
        '-W',
    ]

    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        print("Backup restored onto the test server.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error occurred while restoring the backup:")
        print(e.stdout)  # Print the output from the command
        print(e.stderr)  # Print the error message, if available


# Define backup file path
backup_file = '/pathtofile/backup_file.dump'  # Update with the desired backup file path
backup_file2 = 'backup_file.dump'  # Update with the desired backup file path

# Backup the production database
backup_database(input_host, input_database, input_password, input_user, backup_file)
print("Backup of the production database created.")

# Create metadata object for test server
output_metadata = MetaData(bind=output_engine)

clear_database(output_engine, output_metadata)
print("Test server cleared.")

restore_database(output_host, output_datebase, output_password, output_user, backup_file2)
print("Backup restored onto the test server.")
```

This code appears to be creating a dump file, but it is not successfully restoring to the test database.
If I get this code to work, how do I specify file paths within Azure Functions, is this a suitable solution to run from Azure Functions?
If not, how to get sqlalchemy to successfully clear test data/metadata, then copy over data from prod every night?

Comment: What's the problem? If you get an error message, what is it?  If you don't get an error, what indicates that it is not successful?

Comment: @jjanes in my local repo, a dump file appears, but in my database I don't see the data being restored. Even if it did appear, I'm not sure how to modify the code to be compatible with azure functions

Comment: able to [copy](https://i.imgur.com/b5WwKvN.png) data from [source](https://i.imgur.com/DiTd4l6.png) to [destination](https://i.imgur.com/OitZWRI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have referred MSDOC [Psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/).

```py
import  psycopg2
src_conn_string = "SourceConnectionString"
dst_conn_string = "DStConnectionString"
try:
src_conn = psycopg2.connect(src_conn_string)
src_cursor = src_conn.cursor()
print("Connected to source database.")
try:
dst_conn = psycopg2.connect(dst_conn_string)
dst_cursor = dst_conn.cursor()
print("Connected to destination database.")
try:
src_cursor.execute(
"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'"
)
tables = src_cursor.fetchall()
for  table  in  tables:
src_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {0}".format(table[0]))

rows = src_cursor.fetchall()

for  row  in  rows:
dst_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES {1}".format(table[0],  row))
print("Data transferred successfully.")
except  psycopg2.Error  as  e:
print("Error transferring data: ",  e)
finally:
dst_conn.commit()
dst_cursor.close()
dst_conn.close()
print("Destination database connection closed.")
except  psycopg2.Error  as  e:
print("Error connecting to destination database: ",  e)
finally:
src_cursor.close()
src_conn.close()
print("Source database connection closed.")
except  psycopg2.Error  as  e:
print("Error connecting to source database: ",  e)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**In Azure:**

**Source:**

[image]

**Destination:**

[image]